# Is it possible to set Huawei App Gallery email notifications for app reviews?

Tags: android, huawei-developers

I'm trying to set my Huawei App Gallery (https://developer.huawei.com) project to send email notifications when my app gets reviewed but I can't find any options for setting them up on AppGallery Connect. It would be nice to set up email notifications for both successful and unsuccessful reviews instead of having to check AppGallery Connect regularly.

The documentation doesn't mention anything about email notifications for app reviews either so I'm wondering if the option even exists. If it does exist, I'm hoping someone can lead me to where the settings can be updated.

I've tried going through all the available AppGallery Connect options but can't find anything related to email notifications for app review (this includes all tabs shown: Distribute, Operate, Analyze).

My personal account notification settings could be another place to check but every time I try to access the settings (Manage account > Privacy Center > Notifications) I always get an error (tried several times throughout the span of a month) stating:

> The system is busy. Please try again later.